# How to calculate waypoints between multiple waypoints?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vector

So for example I have an array with 3 waypoints: 
`[ [ 526, 1573, 24 ], [ 2224, 809, -1546 ], [ 6869, 96, -3074 ] ]`

I also know I want to rest for lets say `n` times between between arriving at the first and last waypoint. So in the end I want an array of `n` points.

How do I go about finding those `n` resting-points in JS?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Note this is not a single object! Imagine each axis being one person. They have to stop the same amount of time and at the same time but they do not have to be at the same place obviously.

Comment: May I ask why this is getting down-voted?

Comment: Not my downvote, but you could have provided more info, for example an attempt at a solution / where you're getting stuck if you can't find one. A cynical person might suspect a question like this is an attempt to get out of doing homework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use linear interpolation.

A quick example:

```js
const POINTS = [ [ 526, 1573, 24 ], [ 2224, 809, -1546 ], [ 6869, 96, -3074 ] ];
const N = 10;

function getDistance(point1, point2) {
    // speed in 3d space is mutated according only to the X distance,
    // to keep speed constant in X dimension
    return Math.abs(point1[0] - point2[0]);
}

function go(points, n) {
    const pointDistances = points.slice(1).map((point, index) => getDistance(points[index], point));

    const fullDistance = pointDistances.reduce((sum, distance) => sum + distance, 0);

    const distancePerSection = fullDistance / n;

    return points.slice(1)
        .reduce((last, point, index) => {
            const thisDistance = pointDistances[index];

            const numRestPoints = Math.max(0, Math.floor(thisDistance / distancePerSection) - 1);

            if (!numRestPoints) {
                return last.concat([point]);
            }

            const thisYVector = point[1] - points[index][1];
            const thisZVector = point[2] - points[index][2];

            return last.concat(new Array(numRestPoints).fill(0)
                .reduce((section, item, restIndex) => {
                    return section.concat([[
                        points[index][0] + (restIndex + 1) * distancePerSection,
                        points[index][1] + (restIndex + 1) * thisYVector * distancePerSection / thisDistance,
                        points[index][2] + (restIndex + 1) * thisZVector * distancePerSection / thisDistance
                    ]]);
                }, [])
                .concat([point])
            );

        }, points.slice(0, 1));
}

function test() {
    const result = go(POINTS, N);

    if (result.length !== N) {
        throw new Error('Must be N length');
    }

    if (!result[0].every((value, index) => value === POINTS[0][index])) {
        throw new Error('Doesn\'t start at the first point');
    }
    if (!result[N - 1].every((value, index) => value === POINTS[POINTS.length - 1][index])) {
        throw new Error('Doesn\'t end at the last point');
    }

    if (!POINTS.slice(1, N - 1).every(point =>
        result.some(resultPoint => resultPoint.every((value, index) => value === point[index]))
    )) {
        throw new Error('Doesn\'t go through every provided point');
    }

    console.log(result.slice(1).map((point, index) => getDistance(point, result[index])));

    console.log('The result passed the tests!');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

test();
```

I'm basically going through the list of points, and determining if there should exist any rest points between them, inserting them if so.

Please comment if you want further clarification!

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was thinking wrong and X does not need to have the same distance-delta all the time. I found your solution helpful and with interpolation I created a similar one my own. Could you have a look and maybe explain me the difference?
Thank you!

Comment: Your approach is using an imperative style, while mine is functional. I'm looping through the array of coordinates, while you're looping through the pauses, which involves a different (and I would say slightly more convoluted) way of calculating the points, although it does more explicitly define N points including rest points.

Comment: First I thought I would not need the constant X-speed but I was wrong just as my solution. In this case I thank you very much and I'll accept your answer! It works like a charm!

Comment: Hey again! I know some time passed but I'm having issues with points in the other direction. For example if the array is like this: `[ [ 6869, 96, -3074 ], [ 2224, 809, -1546 ], [ 526, 1573, 24 ]  ]`. It seems like it would add the delta-distances from X up all the time. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this problem now with linear interpolation:

My solution:

```
var waypoints = [[526,1573,24],[2224,809,-1546],[6869,96,-3074]];

var pauses = 20;

generateWaypopints();

function generateWaypopints(){
    var newWaypoints = [];
    var progressAtMainPoints = 1 / (waypoints.length - 1)
    var pausesBetweenWaypoints = pauses * progressAtMainPoints;
    var progressAtPauses = 1 / pausesBetweenWaypoints;

    newWaypoints.push(waypoints[0]);

    var sector = 0;
    var pausesInSector = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < pauses; i++){
        var progress = progressAtPauses * (pausesInSector + 1)
        var x = Math.round(waypoints[sector][0] + (waypoints[sector + 1][0] - waypoints[sector][0]) * progress);
        var y = Math.round(waypoints[sector][1] + (waypoints[sector + 1][1] - waypoints[sector][1]) * progress);
        var z = Math.round(waypoints[sector][2] + (waypoints[sector + 1][2] - waypoints[sector][2]) * progress);

        if(progress >= 1){
            sector++;
            pausesInSector = 0;
        }else
            pausesInSector++;

        newWaypoints.push([x,y,z]);
    }
    console.log(newWaypoints);
    return newWaypoints;
}
```

Comment: This is a viable solution if you don't need a constant X-speed but in my case this is wrong.